# Hibernate Save/Update/Delete OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-5.x

I have **OneToMany** relationship in my Hibernate Entitylike below:

***Form Entity:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "form_master")
public class Form {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Question> questions;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  public String getName() {
     return name;
  }

  public void setName(final String name) {
     this.name = name;
  }


    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "form", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}
```

***Question Entity:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    private long id;
    private Form form;
    private String text;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_id", nullable = true)
    public Form getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(Form form) {
        this.form = form;
    }
}
```

Now when I am saving a new fresh **Form** json as per below:

```
{"name":"Test Form", "questions" : [{"text" : "Question 1"}, {"text" : "Question 2"}]}}
```

So it is creating one new form and 2 new questions. But in the edit time if user delete question 2 and add a new question 3 and send a json like below:

```
{"id" : 1, "name":"Test Form", "questions" : [{"id" : 2, "text" : "Question 1"}, {"text" : "Question 3"}]}}
```

Then Question 2 is not deleting from DB and Question 3 is added as new Question.

So, I need help why this Question 2 is not deleting?

I am using saveOrUpdate of whole form, converted from JSON.

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(form);
```

Comment: Could you provide code example of your delete functionality? And If I understood correctly you send questions to delete and create in one request. Maybe it would be better to separate them?

Comment: You need to add your business code, we can't tell what's happening by json alone

Comment: @Mara  I am using saveOrUpdate of whole form, converted from JSON.

getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(form);

Comment: @Suvonkar according to java doc: 
void saveOrUpdate(Object object) - Either save(Object) or pdate(Object) the given instance, depending upon resolution of the unsaved-value checks (see the manual for discussion of unsaved-value checking).
 void saveOrUpdate(String entityName, Object object) - Either save(String, Object) or update(String, Object) the given instance, depending upon resolution of the unsaved-value checks (see the manual for discussion of unsaved-value checking).

So why should it delete something?

Comment: @Mara, I have used orphanRemoval . Please refer belo link for example - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#example-one-to-many-with-orphan-removal

Comment: Show the code where you do deletion. Looking at entities we cannot help much.
Show the entire method..

Comment: @Suvonkar sorry, without your code I also can't help. Configuration of entities looks fine but it can be just a small mistake in delete functionality.

Comment: This is probably because the code where you translate your incoming JSON to the object isn't properly removing the entry that isn't being provided but instead just overlaying the changes.  For the map, its likely updating question 1, adding question 3, and leaving question 2 unaffected.  As others have said without seeing how you're taking the JSON and applying it to your entity model from the DB, its hard to diagnose completely.  This probably isn't a Hibernate problem but a JSON data usage problem.